# PHP File Encoding

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I recently noticed that the file encoding of the pages I create in my editor are all over the place. Some are saved as ANSI, some are "UTF-8 Without BOM". I am referring to PHP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript files.

What is the best format to save my files in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advised way to go is to use UTF-8 everywhere in your web application. It includes :

- File encoding
- Database charset and encoding
- String handling
- HTML charset output

A nice cheatsheet : http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet

Edit : Just want to add, related to your question context, that PHP don't handle file encoding in UTF-8 with BOM. Use UTF-8 without BOM and you'll be just fine.

Comment: Hi, Thank you! I always use UTF-8 everywhere but I never paid attention to how the files themselves were saved.

Answer (score 1):

I vote fore UTF-8 without BOM. Note though that if you only use regular English characters, ASCII and UTF-8 files will almost always be identical! This means that your editor may read the charset as ASCII even though you saved it as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do a *lot* of CJK work, you should save your files in UTF-8 without a BOM.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is what I use...

It is best for English.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8